# waitforbuttonpress() matplotlib possible bug

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

Consider a refreshed figure inside a loop as per the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fun_example():

    plt.ion()
    for ite in range(3):
        x = np.linspace(-2,6,100)
        y = (ite+1)*x

        figura = plt.figure(1)
        plt.plot(x,y,'-b')
        plt.waitforbuttonpress()
        plt.close()
    #endfor ite

#enddef fun_example

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun_example()
#endif main
```

The idea is to inspect the figure with the mouse (for example, during debugging use the zoom option in the toolbar of the figure), and once it is done, press a button to go on with the code. At least in my case (windows 7, python 3.4.4, spyder 3.0.0dev), if I intend to mouse click in the graph for zooming, the effect is the same than press-button. In other words *waitforbuttonpress()* returns *True*, and the figure is gone.

Any suggestion? might it be a bug? Thank all of you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.waitforbuttonpress), `.waitforbuttonpress()` will return `True` if a key was pressed, and `False` if a mouse button was pressed. Therefore, what you want is probably something like this:

```
while True:
    if plt.waitforbuttonpress():
        break
```